# How to add timeout to a helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart which pulls a lot of images from various registries and deploys a lot of pods. It runs a lot of k8s jobs before getting the pods up.

Overall, helm install command takes huge time, so usually my helm install  will also have --timeout 3600.

Like: helm install --name   will also have --timeout 3600

Can I embed this --timeout 1800 to the helm chat **itself**? (rather than providing a command line parameter)

Comment: Hey bro, maybe if you post in here: https://devops.stackexchange.com, the DevOps community can help you better.

Comment: Posted https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12413/how-to-add-timeout-to-a-helm-chart

Comment: unfortunately, you can't.

Comment: Isn't would be better to pull all the images before you run helm install? So you will not need a huge timeout to wait for all the images be pulled.

Comment: Doesnt work that way at the moment, for some business reasons

Comment: @DanielMarques what makes you think like that? there is `imagePullPolicy` to handle unnecessary pulls.

Comment: imagePullPolicy is set to: IfNotPresent -> can that be improved?

Comment: @KamolHasan you are right, this only gonna help at the first time the helm release is installed, I suggested that to decrease the timeout value argument.

Comment: @Madhusoodan I think that IfNotPresent is the best approach because the images will only be pulled from a remote registry if isn't locally in the machine.

Comment: @DanielMarques: Ok, still my chart takes a lot of time to get deployed. I wish we had a method of putting timeout in the chart somewhere. Thanks!